# Hibernate 6.4 in debug logging do not start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am migrating my project to Spring 6 and Hibernate 6.4.4. Everything is working +/- fine, but I have big problem with debugging.

When I change in `log4j2.properties` logging to debug I get error from hibernate. But in info mode works everything good.

log4j2.properties:

```
#rootLogger.level                  = info
rootLogger.level                  = debug
```

The error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EntityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webApplicationContext.xml]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.model.jdbc.JdbcMutationOperation.getSqlString()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.persister.collection.mutation.RowMutationOperations.getUpdateRowOperation()" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:939)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.model.jdbc.JdbcMutationOperation.getSqlString()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.persister.collection.mutation.RowMutationOperations.getUpdateRowOperation()" is null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1764)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.model.jdbc.JdbcMutationOperation.getSqlString()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.persister.collection.mutation.RowMutationOperations.getUpdateRowOperation()" is null
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.logStaticSQL(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:630)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4780)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 46 more
```

Part of `webApplicationContext.xml`

```xml
<bean id="EntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mydomain"/>      
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" /> 
     <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/> <!-- true for DEBUGING -->
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="10"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I check dependences and deleting parts of xml but no result.

I want to be able to use debug mode!

Comment: At first glance, it sounds like a bug in Hibernate (specifically in `org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.logStaticSQL`). I'd suggest reporting it to Hibernate (see https://hibernate.org/community/, and then "Issue tracker").